# Error when installing artifactory service

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, artifactory

I downloaded artifactory-oss-5.6.2 from JFrog official website. I managed to activate it using artifactory.bat and login to localhost:8081.

I ran the batch installService.bat which ended with message:   **The service 'artifactory' has been installed.**
But when I try to start it(the service) I get Error 1053: **`The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`**.

What I did was:
Downloaded Java JDK 8.
- Defined path `JAVA_HOME = jdk1.8.0_152` directory.
- Defined path `JAVA_JRE = jre1.8.0_152` directory.
- Defined path `ARTIFACTORY_HOME = artifactory-oss-5.6.2` directory. (I also tried without setting this enviroment variable).
- Tried to run **installService.bat** (also once as administrator) - the script installs the Artifactory as a service but when I try to start it I get the error message 1053 above.

I currently have windows 7 professional. 
I also tried the same installation on a Windows 10 home and it didn't work with the same error.

Please help:
**How can I install Artifactory as a service?**

Comment: Without wishing to come across as rude, do you not reckon that JFrog official website would be a more appropriate host for your question?

Comment: @Compo As this is an OSS version of Artifactory he is posting it in the right place. 

Davis8988 Do you see anything in the logs of Artifactory or the Tomcat?

Comment: @Ariel, if you bought a vehicle which had been designed and sold to drive perfectly on two platforms, (on and off road); but when it arrived it didn't work on your chosen platform, (roads), what what would you do? Ask around groups of people who have vehicles? or take it back to the point of sale? My last response echoes my preference. The OP isn't trying to do something which requires an in depth knowledge of the coding or usage of the software, they just want to set it up for use. The official site should provide support for something as simple as setup and installation of their products!

Comment: @Compo You are right if you **bought** a vehicle, but this is Open Source, means no one **bought** anything.
Using Support is a paid option which everyone can choose rather buy JFrog software and get the support or download the OSS and use the community forum.
 Anyhow, I didn't just write that, I also asked him what he sees in the logs to try and help him with the issue.